# Uniform script for calling ads?

Tags: android-studio

I have an .apk and it has WAY too many ads with way too many numerical restrictions on how many times you get to do something with its features unless you get the full version then it changes its limits for you, and I was wondering if there's a uniform way of putting ads in your application? Similar to how when incrementing something in a formula, it's extremely common to use i++ even though you could technically use any variable. I decompiled it and was going to use grep to find any instances of them and remove them so I don't have any annoying ads popping up while I'm on the app. There are other modifications I'm doing on it as well, but that's the one I need help with.

Looking for something generally along the lines of:

```
If (this condition is met) {
 generate this ad;
```

}

Comment: Usually an ad network will state what company they are in the (i)/more info button of the ad. See what network it is, go to their website/docs for their sdk and you can track down the network-specific "`showAd`" call

Comment: @quidproquo that's an excellent start, thank you! I'm going to do that and follow up with what happened